# How to use google app script addon by app script manifest or local environment?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, add-in, add-on, google-apps-marketplace

I am new to **google app script**. I don't know how to **deploy the Google add-on**. I have tried some setups for deployment but have not been able to do the deployment. so, I have some questions below.?

1. Can we use the google app script add-on without deploying on google marketplace? or
   how to use google add-on local environment?.
   or
   Can we use the google add-on just by **passing appscript.json?** as we do in **excel**? In the **excel add-in** we just pass the **manifest file** and we put the dist folder on the local server so anyone can use that add-in.

Can anyone guide me about this.

Comment: Per sites guidelines, only one question per post is allowed.

Comment: okay I will add modify the question.

Comment: The post still have multiple questions.

Comment: What about if you start by reading https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons?

Comment: I don't want to show my code to anyone for this what do we have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/ and https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace

To deploy an add-on (i.e. create a version of the script that can be used by an app in the Google Workspace Marketplace) see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments

To test an add-on (install it without having to publish it in the Google Workspace Marketplace)
See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/testing-editor-addons.

To publish an app in the Google Workspace Marketplace see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/publish-add-on-overview and https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/how-to-publish.

Sheets and other Google Workspace products are on the cloud, so you can't copy a file somewhere to install and add-on. If you have are a Google Workspace customer you can publish a private app in the Marketplace. Then the admin can install the app for its users.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, sir. I have tried all the steps you have provided. I am able to deploy and test the add-on. Now, I have added 2 new members' Gmail as test users in the google cloud project and When I open the spreadsheet from their spreadsheet I cannot see my add-on. I don't know why this was happening. Can you please guide me on this?

Comment: And i don't want to show my code to anyone for this what we have to do?

Comment: How did yo add test users? The other users would have to have access to the code and install it for themselves as you did.
If you want users to install your add-on without access to the code you have to publish it in the Google Workspace Marketplace. If all the users are in the same domain then you can do a private application, which doesn't require reviews. Otherwise, you have to make a public application and go through the OAuth scopes review and app review. If you want you can make your app unlisted so that it doesn't show up in searches.